# Obtain component id from javascript

Tags: javascript, dart, angular-dart

In dart we can obtain dom element through 'querySelector' method. But I need a reverse kind method: insert data into "dart component" element from Javascript. Is there a way to achieve that?

I have try:

html file:

```
<comp></comp>
<script>
  document.getElementById('mydiv').text = "HELLO";
  document.getElementById('myd').text = "HELLO";
</script>
```

dart component:

```
@Component (
  selector: 'comp',
  template: '<div #mydiv id="myd">12345</div>',
)
class ModelerComponent {
```

PS: I need that because my js library requires element id, and there is no option to port it.

Comment: Where is the `<script>` tag in your application? Is `<comp></comp>` your root component of the Angular application? Your script needs to wait until `<div #mydiv ...>` actually exists. Angular probably takes more time to initialize then the script.

Comment: +1 to Gunter's comment. I'd suggest having the code run after ngOnInit runs in the component. Have the <script> expose a function and call it from the dart code. That would guarantee the dom is ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to comments, I've solve the problem:
I place code which initializes JS library into ngOnInit() method of a component. So the js library is initialised right after an angular component.